# SimpleEKDemo Example with allowsEditing = YES but show only "Done" button in iPad

Tags: xcode, ipad, eventkit

The SimpleEKDemo example is delivered with "Targeted Device Family = iPhone" in the Build tag of Project Settings. It works for both iPhone and iPad, the "Edit" barButton showed in the EKEventViewController.

However, if I changed the "Targeted Device Family" to either "iPad" or "iPhone/Ipad", it is still working in iPhone simulator and device, but not the iPad simulator or device. No matter the allowsEditing is configured to YES or NO, the EKEventViewController will show "Done" barButton instead of "Edit" in the iPad simulator or device.

I deployed the EventKit framework to my own project and the Kal NativeCal Example and had the same issue.

I searched apple development forum and internet but no information on this issue.

If you had the same issue before or have any suggestion, please help.

Thanks.

BTW, a few development environment information for reference:

1. Mac OS 10.6.5
2. Xcode 3.2.5
3. Project Base SDK: 4.2
4. Project iOS Deployment Target: 4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the answer from https://devforums.apple.com/message/352279.

The modalInPopover must be configured as NO. For example:

eventViewController.modalInPopover = NO;

Comment: HUGE FIND!  I've been screwing around with this problem precisely, using Kal on an iPad too.  I wish I'd thought to look here four hours ago.